# How to set a custom loss function in Spark MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, regression, apache-spark-mllib

I would like to use my own loss function instead of the squared loss for the [linear regression model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-linear-methods.html) in spark MLlib. So far can't find any part in the documentation that mentions if it is even possible.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR;** it is not easy to use a custom loss function because you can not simply pass a loss function to spark models. However, you can easily write a customized model for yourself.

**Long answer:**
If you look at the code of [LinearRegressionWithSGD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LinearRegression.scala#L87) you will see:

```
class LinearRegressionWithSGD private[mllib] (
    private var stepSize: Double,
    private var numIterations: Int,
    private var regParam: Double,
    private var miniBatchFraction: Double)
  extends GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm[LinearRegressionModel] with Serializable {

  private val gradient = new LeastSquaresGradient() #Loss Function
  private val updater = new SimpleUpdater()
  @Since("0.8.0")
  override val optimizer = new GradientDescent(gradient, updater) #Optimizer
    .setStepSize(stepSize)
    .setNumIterations(numIterations)
    .setRegParam(regParam)
    .setMiniBatchFraction(miniBatchFraction)
```

So, let's look at how the least squared loss function is implemented [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/Gradient.scala#L285):

```
class LeastSquaresGradient extends Gradient {
  override def compute(data: Vector, label: Double, weights: Vector): (Vector, Double) = {
    val diff = dot(data, weights) - label
    val loss = diff * diff / 2.0
    val gradient = data.copy
    scal(diff, gradient)
    (gradient, loss)
  }

  override def compute(
      data: Vector,
      label: Double,
      weights: Vector,
      cumGradient: Vector): Double = {
    val diff = dot(data, weights) - label
    axpy(diff, data, cumGradient)
    diff * diff / 2.0
  }
}
```

So, you can simply write a class like `LeastSquaresGradient` and implement the `compute` function and use it in your `LinearRegressionWithSGD` model.